# C# ListBox/ListView not showing elements - Metro UI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, microsoft-metro

I am using a ListBox in my Metro UI media player, but the ListBox doesn't show any text when I run it. I don't have any errors or so, but there is no text. I have also tried to use a ListView and not a ListBox, but the result was the same. What can I do ?

I am using the next code for the ListBox on the XAML part of the page

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemListBox">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PathToFile}"  
                       FontSize="24" Margin="5,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HasVideo}" 
                       FontSize="16" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

and the next code on the page C# code :

```
 public static ListBox ListBoxIstance = null;
 public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ListBoxIstance = ItemListBox;

            ItemListBox.ItemsSource = Data_Repository.MediaData.MediaList;
            ItemListBox.DataContext = Data_Repository.MediaData.MediaList;

        }
```

where MediaList is a list declared as it follows

```
public static List<MediaFile> MediaList = new List<MediaFile>();
```

and MediaFile is a class

```
    public class MediaFile
    {
        public TimeSpan Duration = TimeSpan.Zero;

        public bool HasAudio = false;
        public bool HasVideo = false;

        public String PathToFile = null;

        public MediaFile(string _pathToFile)
        {
            PathToFile = _pathToFile;
        }

    }
```

I am using the next code to update the MediaList and the ItemListBox

```
foreach (var pathToFile in files)
     {
         MediaList.Add(new MediaFile(pathToFile.Path));
         MainPage.ListBoxIstance.UpdateLayout();
     }
```

EDIT : After some suggestions :

That's how the MediaFile class looks like :

```
    public class MediaFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _hasAudio;
        public bool HasAudio 
        { 
            get { return _hasAudio; }
            set
            {
                _hasAudio = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasAudio");
            } 
        }

        private bool _hasVideo;
        public bool HasVideo
        {
            get { return _hasVideo; }
            set
            {
                _hasVideo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HasVideo");
            }
        }

    private String _pathToFile;

    public String PathToFile
    {
        get { return _pathToFile; }
        set
        {
            _pathToFile = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PathToFile");
        }
    }


        public MediaFile(string pathToFile)
        {
            PathToFile = pathToFile;
        }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
            if (propertyChanged != null)
            {
                propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

and I am using

```
public static ObservableCollection<MediaFile> MediaList = new ObservableCollection<MediaFile>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind to public fields in your item class. Turn the class members into public properties:

```
public class MediaFile
{
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public bool HasAudio { get; set; }
    public bool HasVideo { get; set; }
    public String PathToFile { get; set; }

    public MediaFile(string _pathToFile)
    {
        PathToFile = _pathToFile;
    }
}
```

Then use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`. That would automatically update the `ItemsSource` binding when items are added or removed. No need to call UpdateLayout.

```
public ObservableCollection<MediaFile> MediaList =
    new ObservableCollection<MediaFile>();
```

If you also want to  update the UI when any of the property values changes after a MediaFile object has been added to the list, you also have to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.aspx) interface:

```
public class MediaFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
        if (propertyChanged != null)
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private bool hasVideo
    public bool HasVideo
    {
        get { return hasVideo; }
        set
        {
             hasVideo = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("HasVideo"); 
        }
    }

    // other properties
```

}

Comment: I have done all the modifications, but the ListBox still doesn't show me anything.

Comment: It should have shown the initial values at least. Did you really use an `ObservableCollection`? And it is not necessary to set the ListBox's `DataContext` when you set the `ItemsSource` property directly, without binding.

Comment: Yes, I used ObservableCollection. I removed the line with DataContext  and I used the INotifyPropertyChanged as you told me, yet nothing shows on the screen.

Comment: Ok, I don't know how, but now it's working. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You can only bind with `properties` and not with `fields`. Change fields to properties.

```
public bool HasVideo {get;set;}
public String PathToFile {get;set;}
```

Comment: I have done the modifications, but theListBox still doesn't show me anything.

Comment: When you set `ItemsSource` of listbox, list was populated or it gets populated after setting ItemsSource?

Comment: After, but I was using the MainPage.ListBoxIstance.UpdateLayout(); and now I replaced the list with an ObservableCollection.